# Do periods need to be escaped in html?

Tags: html

I'm trying to learn more about xss attacks and how to prevent them but I have a very simple question that I cannot find the answer to.

Should periods be escaped in html as a stronger measure against any hacks/attacks or are they fine as they are?

If this answer does exist and I just missed it, I am sorry for asking a duplicate question but a link or answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They do not need to be escaped. Arguably the only thing that *needs* to be escaped is `<`, but `>` is often also escaped.

Comment: @KevinB — Unless you are inside an attribute value.

Comment: Oh boy, so I've been escaping commas and apostrophes for nothing?

Comment: well, apostrophes should be escaped if you're inserting it into an attribute in an htmlstring if the attribute is using single quotes as a wrapper, otherwise, yes, escaping them doesn't really add any additional security.

Comment: Which language are you using when you are doing the escaping? Is it a server language like PHP or just javascript? Most server languages have built-in functions or external libraries which handle correctly escaping html, javascript, URLs etc. for you and save you the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they do not. Take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet